# Copy selected columns from one DataTable to another

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a scenario where-in I have a DataTable with certain columns "Col1, Col2, Col3". I want to copy just "Col2, Col3" into another DataTable which has a primary key "ID". What is the best way to copy them. There are 5000+ records and performance is a key factor.

I tried with Select, DefaultView.RowsFilter but no success. I know one option is to loop through all records an copy data one by one in second DataTable. But wanted to know a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this code (visual basic):

```
dim dt1 as new datatable()
dim dt2 as new datatable()
dim dv as dataview = dt1.defaultview
dv.ToTable(false, new string[] { "col1", "col2" })
```

If you want distinct rows then put true in first `ToTable` argument.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It works. However since my dt2 already a primary key column, instead of appending rows from dt1, it overrides my primary column. Is there a way to keep my existing columns?

Comment: if you want to append dt1 to dt2 then try it dt2.merge(dv.ToTable(false, new string[] { "col1", "col2" }),True,MissingSchemaAction.Add)). This will preserve your schema of dt2.

Comment: The code forgets to assign dt2